# Expected Identifier and undeclared identifier errors in SDL black and white conversion

Tags: c, sdl

I'm trying to make an SDL image converter to make an image in black and white. So far my code worked fine, it loaded an image from a file location, all I needed to do was an in the greyscale conversion,here is the black and white conversion code:

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
Uint32 pixel = pixels[y * image->w + x];

for (int y = 0; y++ < image->h; y++)
   {
    for (int x = 0; x < image->w; x++)

    Uint32 *pixel = (Uint32*)image->pixels
    Uint8 r=0,g=0,b=0;
    SDL_GetRBG(image->&r,&g,&b);
    Uint8 v = 0.212671f * r + 0.715160f * g + 0.072169f * b;
    Uint32 pixel = SDL_MapRGB(image->format,v,v,v);
    pixels[y * image->w + x] = pixel;

   }
```

I get the following errors:

```
SDL.c:73:3: error: expected expression
                Uint32 *pixel = (Uint32*)image->pixels

SDL.c:75:3: warning: implicit declaration of function 'SDL_GetRBG' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                SDL_GetRBG(image->&r,&g,&b);

SDL.c:75:21: error: expected identifier
                SDL_GetRBG(image->&r,&g,&b);
                                  ^
SDL.c:75:22: error: use of undeclared identifier 'r'
                SDL_GetRBG(image->&r,&g,&b);

SDL.c:76:25: error: use of undeclared identifier 'r'
                Uint8 v = 0.212671f * r + 0.715160f * g + 0.072169f * b;

SDL.c:76:41: error: use of undeclared identifier 'g'
                Uint8 v = 0.212671f * r + 0.715160f * g + 0.072169f * b;

SDL.c:76:41: error: use of undeclared identifier 'g'
                Uint8 v = 0.212671f * r + 0.715160f * g + 0.072169f * b;

SDL.c:76:41: error: use of undeclared identifier 'g'
                Uint8 v = 0.212671f * r + 0.715160f * g + 0.072169f * b;
```

Comment: Just fyi, you seem to be missing a set of  `{` and `}` in the posted code for the inner nested loop. Unless, of course, your intention was to simply declare `Uint32 *pixel` a total of `image->w` times, an identifier name overused in this code several times).

Comment: Ah thank you for the spot! That helped take out a few of the errors :)

Comment: Since `x` is used in the last line, that should be included in the inner loop's code block or the statement will probably break an array.

Comment: You're also missing at least one semi-colon, and I see no logical use for the top-most `pixel` declaration whatsoever. And I haven't a clue what  `image->&r` is trying to do.

Comment: And did you *really* intend on double-incrementing `y` (once in the conditional, once in the increment step of your `for-loop`) ?

Comment: grayScale = (r+g+b)/3;   *pixel = grayScale<<16 | grayScale<<8 | grayScale;

Comment: @WhozCraig No I didn't mean to double increment, thanks and  do you mean the "void SDL_GetRGB((image)->&r, &g, &b); line? and thanks Weather Vane! :)

Comment: After doing some changes I now have only two errors, SDL.c:75:27: error: expected ')'
                        void SDL_GetRGB((image)->&r, &g, &b);
and  SDL.c:75:9: error: conflicting types for 'SDL_GetRGB'
                        void SDL_GetRGB((image)->&r, &g, &b);

Comment: The [`SDL_GetRGB`](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_GetRGB) functions takes an `Uint32` value, a pixel format, and `Uint8*` receivers. That "thing" you're trying to do isn't that. Follow the API. I know *nothing* about SDL, but it will probably look something [like this](http://pastebin.com/FUgaDdHS).

Answer (score 0):

the following seems to be what the posted code is trying to accomplish

```
// this assumes the transparancy byte is the high order byte
int x = 0;
int y = 0;

Uint32 *pPixel;
Uint8   transparancy;
Uint8   r;
Uint8   g;
Uint8   b;
Uint8   gray;

for (int y = 0; y < image->h; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < image->w; x++)
    {
        // get address of pixel
        pPixel = &(image->pixels[y][x]);

        // extract individual color values
        // may want to use the factors: 0.212671f, 0.715160f, 0.072169f
        // rather than the following simple shift+and
        transparancy = (*pPixel >>24)&0xFF;
        r = (*pPixel >>16)&0xFF;
        g = (*pPixel >> 8)&0xFF;
        b = (*pPixel >> 0)&0xFF;

        // calculate gray value
        gray = (Uint8)( (Uint32)(r+g+b)/3 )&0xFF;

        // update the pixel
        *pPixel = (Uint32)transparancy << 24 | 
                  (Uint32)gray<<16 | 
                  (Uint32)gray<<8 | 
                  (Uint32)gray;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah it is :)  Thank you! But what am I doing wrong with my current code? At the moment im getting                                                     *
SDL.c:75:32: error: expected ')'
                        void SDL_GetRBG(pixel, image->format, &r,&g,&b);
                                                    ^
SDL.c:75:19: note: to match this '('
 void SDL_GetRBG(pixel, image->format, &r,&g,&b)             
SDL.c:75:20: error: a parameter list without types is only allowed in a function definition
 void SDL_GetRBG(pixel, image->format, &r,&g,&b);
errors

Comment: There are a lot of reasons your code is having problems.  Some have been covered in other comments (like missing braces for the inner for-loop), but you still have SDL_GetRBG (which doesn't exist, use `SDL_GetRGB`), you're not actually passing the surface format to `SDL_GetRGB`, and you're missing a semicolon in one of the several conflicting `pixel` declarations.